# Close a popover

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, popover

I have managed to show a popover in my app. It can be closed with a swipi down. Works great. However, it is adviced to also show a button to close the popover. I tried to add this to the code, with all the tips on pop-ons and pop-overs given on the site, but sofa I failed. Can someone help me out? Must be an easy command but for a starter in xcode/swift it ins't easy to find.

The code to show the popover and the code in the popover itself:

...

```
      //The popover code in the ContentView that starts the popover
      Button(action: {
              presentPopup = true
            }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "questionmark.square")
            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                   })
            .padding(.leading)
            .popover(isPresented: $presentPopup, arrowEdge: .bottom) {
            Toelichting()
            .font(.footnote)
            }



//The code in the popover view:
 var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        
        HStack {
        
        Text("Introduction")
            .font(.title2)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            .padding([.top, .leading])
        
        //Spacer ()
        
        // This should be the button to return to the main screen that ins't working
        //   Button  (action: {
        //      self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        //    }, label: {
        //    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
        //    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
        //    })
        //        .padding([.top, .trailing])
        }
        
         Divider()
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .frame(height: 3.0)
            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
```

...

What should be Button action? Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: you'll find your answe here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71026740/swiftui-modal-view/71032376#71032376

Comment: Thanks, tried to add 'dismiss ()' (and not use 'self.dismiss(animated: true, completen: nil) as action for the button to return from the popover view. However, this gives an error message 'Cannot find 'dismiss' in scope'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than dismissing the popover using `dismiss()`, you need to pass a `Binding` value between both views.

In this way, the value of the `Binding` will either be `true`, triggered by the main view, or `false`, triggered inside the popover.

Here's your code:

```
struct TopView: View {
    @State private var presentPopup = true    // This controls the popover
    
    var body: some View {
        //The popover code in the ContentView that starts the popover
        Button {
            presentPopup = true
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "questionmark.square")
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
        }
        .padding(.leading)
        .popover(isPresented: $presentPopup, arrowEdge: .bottom) {
            
            // You need to pass the Binding to the popover
            Toelichting(presentMe: $presentPopup)
                .font(.footnote)
        }
    }
}

struct Toelichting: View {
    
    @Binding var presentMe : Bool    // This is how you trigger the dismissal
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            HStack {
            
            Text("Introduction")
                .font(.title2)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .padding([.top, .leading])
            
            Spacer ()
            
                // This should be the button to return to the main screen that NOW IT'S FINALLY working
               Button  (action: {
                   
                   // Change the value of the Binding
                   presentMe.toggle()
                   
                }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "xmark.circle")
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                })
                    .padding([.top, .trailing])
            }
            
             Divider()
                .padding(.horizontal)
                .frame(height: 3.0)
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @HunterLion,
Thanks a lot. However, get an error on:
...

struct Toelichting_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Toelichting(presentMe: $presentMe)
    }
}
...

At first it was () and xcode suggested to add $presentme, but nog it is giving an error: Instance member '$presentMe' of type 'Toelichting' cannot be used on instance of nested type 'Toelichting.Toelichting_Previews'

Can you help me out? Changing the dollar sign to the other one doesn't help ...

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Hi rwdg. In the struct Toelichting_Previews, which is only necessary to see the preview on the right side of the screen but it does not affect your app, call the view as follows: Toelichting(presentMe: .constant(true)) - do not forget the dot before "constant". This will allow your program to compile. You use this trick when you do not have a State var to pass to the Binding. Alternatively, you can just comment out the whole struct Toelichting_Previews (select the whole struct and press command+/ ).

Comment: Thanks a lot @HunterLion! Works like charm and looks terrific.